# Loading/parsing XML file works locally but not on Wordpress server?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

The below code is used to generate a summary of reviews, and works perfectly locally:

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/business/businessidhere?api_key=apikeyhere");
    $avg = $xml->avgRating;
    $totalnum = $xml->reviewCount;
    $htmlTop = 'Company has an average of ' . $avg . '/5 stars, with a total of ';
    $htmlBom =  $totalnum . ' reviews.'
    ?>
<span class=toptext>
<?php
    echo $htmlTop;
    ?>
<a href="the-company-review-page" target="_blank" style="font-weight:900;">
<?php
    echo $htmlBom;
    ?>
</span>
</a>
```

The code is able to generate perfectly when hosted locally, but as soon as the code is executed on my Wordpress site, the fields $avg and $totalnum are blank. Another plugin that was attempting to perform the same function was also unsuccessful at retrieving the data. I am relatively new to PHP, and getting data from an API this way. I'm thinking it has to be a Wordpress configuration error, but I'm not too sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked what's actually in `$xml` in production? Does it even have content, or does `simplexml_load_file` go "yeah this URL is bogus, have a `false` instead"?

Comment: loading the file with simplexml_load_file works fine on my local machine, and nothing about the API URL changes for production. How should I further investigate this?

Comment: Try checking out your browsers "network" tab to see if you see any clues when trying to load the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

From this line..

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/business/businessidhere?api_key=apikeyhere");
```

I can tell that your server needs to have the **allow_url_fopen** directive turned on. It's normally not on on a production server by default.